# Hot cranking problem on 6.6 duramax

Tags: engine, chevrolet, diesel

6.6 duramax diesel engine cranks good cold but periodically won't crank hot unless I use starting fluid. This usually happens after engine has been turned off about 30 minutes. Also if idles for several minutes accelerator is very slow to react sometimes have to push it several times before it works.

Comment: Which year/model is your Duramax in?

Comment: 2002 Chey 2500hd 4 wheel drive silverado

Comment: Have you tried to prime the fuel system when this happens? I believe the primer pump is on the fuel filter housing.

Comment: Yes with no success it's like it has shut off  fuel to injectors, vapor lock or something

Comment: How long does it take for it to start again? What do you do to get it started? How long do you have to wait for it to start again? You stated "periodically" ... this means it's sporadic and doesn't happen every time?

Comment: Will start with starting fluid or have to wait till engine cools off some. It does not do it every time, it take it by spells

Comment: Unfortunately, intermittent issues are the hardest to diagnose, whether on the Interwebz or in person. I don't have what the issue is, but maybe by what you've written, someone else will.

Comment: Thx anyway I do have a question. Could accelerator shutting off have link to issue?

Comment: I mean, it could be your High Pressure Fuel pump which is at issue. I think you control the accelerator through there as well but I'm unsure.